How to set proxy in Nuxt3?
I can't understand why setting proxy in nuxt 3 doesn't work
When im trying to get data i see incorrect url in development tools

Below is my code, what am i doing wrong?
nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: "2024-04-03",
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["vuetify-nuxt-module", "@pinia/nuxt"],
  
  nitro: {
    devProxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:1337/",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },

  vuetify: {
    moduleOptions: {
      /* module specific options */
    },
    vuetifyOptions: {
      /* vuetify options */
    },
  },
});

pinia
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({
    restaurant: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    async getRestaraunts() {
      

        const { data } = await $fetch('api/restaurants')
        
        console.log(data)
    },
  },
})



I read that i can create an env environment variable and rely on it, but I don’t quite understand how to do this, but I’m more interested in how to register it only in nuxt.config.js

This is because (counterintuitively) you cannot use devProxy injunction with $fetch (for shame).
Instead, tell nitro to proxy specific routes:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: "2024-04-03",
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["vuetify-nuxt-module", "@pinia/nuxt"],
  
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      '/api/**': { 
        proxy: { 
          to: 'http://localhost:1337/**' // make sure this is an ENV driven variable if production does not match
        }
      }
    }
  },

  vuetify: {
    moduleOptions: {
      /* module specific options */
    },
    vuetifyOptions: {
      /* vuetify options */
    },
  },
});

Now $fetch will correctly proxy these routes to your endpoint.

I did it, but anyway proxy url doesnt work
when im trying to fetch, i see this url http://localhost:3000/restaurants in devtools

@Maxim Then change the glob pattern to include /api if your server at 1337 requires that in the path: to: 'http://localhost:1337/api/**

I am maybe too late for that but I think it is caused because in your fetched you did await $fetch('api/restaurants') while you should have written await $fetch('/api/restaurants')
Also, the nitro config should have been  nitro: { devProxy: { "/api/**": {
